# Title font in subplots with axes.title.set_text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have intention in making multiple subplot to present my results. I used subplots from matplotlib. I have a problem with text sizes. As you can see in the trivial code here. In the `plt.title` documentation it says `title(label, fontdict=None, loc='center', pad=None, **kwargs)`

```
import random
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, plot, xlabel, ylabel, legend, close, subplots, title, savefig, get_current_fig_manager, show, pause, clf

x = []
for i in range(10):
    x.append(random.random()*i)

y_1 = []

for i in range(10):
    y_1.append(random.random()*i)
y_2 = []

for i in range(10):
    y_2.append(random.random()*i)


fig, ax = subplots(1, 2, squeeze = False, figsize = (10,10))
ax[0,1].title.set_text('y_1', fontdict = {'font.size':22})
ax[0,1].plot(x,y_1)
ax[0,1].set_xlabel('x')
ax[0,1].set_ylabel('y_1')

ax[0,0].title.set_text('y_2', fontdict = {'font.size':22})
ax[0,0].plot(x,y_2)
ax[0,0].set_xlabel('x')
ax[0,0].set_ylabel('y_2')
```

but if I run this code I get an error `TypeError: set_text() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontdict'`

am I using the wrong command.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is really just a minor issue:

To set the title of a specific axes you should use the [`set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html) method of the axes. Using [`plt.title`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) sets the title of the current axes instance.

Basically replace your `ax[0,0].title.set_text` with `ax[0,0].set_title` and you are good to go!

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply use `fontsize=22` directly , as in
`ax[0,1].set_title('y_1', fontsize=22)`